Can't make an include operation in a one to one relationship
I'm trying to make a one-to-one relationship as it's shown on the learn Microsoft website, but when I try to get it from the repository using a include it gives me this error, and I can't figure out why as I don't have problems with other types of include, only when it's one to one it generates an error:

The expression 'p.BlogHeader' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Those are the classes and the model configurations:
// Principal (parent)
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BlogHeader? BlogHeader { get; set; } // Reference navigation to dependent
}

// Dependent (child)
public class BlogHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Required foreign key property
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } = null!; // Required reference navigation to principal
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Header)
        .WithOne(e => e.Blog)
        .HasForeignKey<BlogHeader>(e => e.BlogId);
}

This is the include operation I'm trying to do
public override Task<Blog?> GetByIdAsync(long blogId)
{
    return DbSet
        .Include(p => p.BlogHeader)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == blogId);
}


I think you want .Include(p => p.Header) since that's the name of the navigation property.  You use the property name in the include, not the entity type.

@DStanley that was my fault when copying the code here. It's correct in the application. Sorry about that...

"since it does not represent a property access" ... I think that whatever the real problem is, you haven't included it in your question. Did you sanitise it too much? What is the DbSet?
